# Purpose and correct name of plastic inserts in 2-stroke cylinder

Tags: small-engine, two-stroke, cylinder

I recently replaced the cylinder and piston on a broken chainsaw 2-stroke engine and I found 2 plastic inserts inside the cylinder. I'm wondering what purpose these serve, and what the correct name for them is.

[image: Plastic inserts inside cylinder]

[image: Plastic inserts outside cylinder]

Comment: Port seals come to mind, but some parts manuals may differ.

Comment: Also, if you gave us the make/model/size of the engine, it would surely help us to understand exactly what you're pointing at. As Mike states, things differ between manufacturers.